# How to set redis key with the output of a bash command

Tags: bash, redis, redis-cli

I'm using redis-cli within a bash script, now I want to save the current date in a specific format into a redis specific key. how do I do that?
I already tried `redis-cli -x SET last-modified $(date +"%D %T")` but without success.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
date +"%D %T" | redis-cli -x SET last-modified
OK
```

```
redis-cli GET last-modified
"05/30/22 08:32:05\n"
```

You can see an example in redis-cli help, only relevant output is presented

```
redis-cli --help
  -x                 Read last argument from STDIN (see example below).

Examples:
  cat /etc/passwd | redis-cli -x set mypasswd
```